# docker run -v works even without VOLUME or mkdir

Tags: docker, volume, mount

What is the use of "VOLUME" or "RUN mkdir /m"?

Even if I do not specify any of these instructions in the Dockerfile, then also "docker run -v ${PWD}/m:/m" works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does VOLUME inside Dockerfile do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862705/what-does-volume-inside-dockerfile-do)

Comment: TL;DR: you probably want to `RUN mkdir` in case the `-v` option wasn’t provided.  You probably don’t want an explicit `VOLUME` unless you’re _very_ clear about what it does.

Comment: @DavidMaze, Even if I build without `RUN mkdir` and without `VOLUME`, the external mount is still working. That is if I supply `-v` option.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a Dockerfile, `VOLUME` marks a directory as a mount point for an external volume. Even if the docker run command doesn't mount an existing folder into that mount point, docker will create a named volume to hold the data.

`RUN mkdir /m` does what `mkdir` does on any Unix system. It makes a directory named `m` at the root of the filesystem.

`docker run -v ...` binds a host directory to a volume inside a container. It will work whether or not the mount point was declared as a volume in a Dockerfile, and it will also create the directory if it doesn't exist. So neither `VOLUME` or `RUN mkdir` are specifically necessary before using that command, though they may be helpful to communicate the intent to the user.

Comment: Directories that are created inside a container using the command "mkdir" gets removed when the container is removed. Is it true that volumes are not removed?

Comment: There are a lot of intricacies around how volumes work. But in general, if you mount a host directory as a volume, then any data would persist on the host. If you don't mount a host directory, docker will create a volume for you. If you then remove the container, the docker volume would be orphaned (but still possible to reuse until you remove it). Reading about the `docker volume` command will go through some of these ideas in more depth.