# Docker use different filesystems in a container

Tags: docker, filesystems, xfs

How can I use different filesystems in a container?
I have tried to make an img with XFS filesystem.

```
mkfs.xfs proba.img
```

It was succesful, but when tried to mount it, get following error. Already tried to use `chmod`, but same error.

```
mount: block device /root/proba.img is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount block device /root/proba.img read-only
```

xfs_info's output: `proba.img is not a mounted XFS filesystem`

Is XFS(or another) filesystem usage possible in a single conatiner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050899/how-to-mount-host-volumes-into-docker-containers-in-dockerfile-during-build) too, it's not possible to mount a filesystem inside a container.

You'll have to mount the new image in the Docker host and expose it to the container as a volume. See question above for examples.