# Mount OpenAFS host volume in GitLab-CI runner to make it accesible in Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, openafs

We have setup a `CentOS 7` repository in `OpenAFS` that we access from our images to install some applications.
This process is entirely manual and we're trying to automate the generation with `GitLab-CI`.

I've set up a runner following [the instructions for setting Docker-in-Docker runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor).

Then, I've modified the `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` file to specify an `OpenAFS` host volume (*volumes* entry):

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "DinD builder"
  url = "https://gitlab.ch/ci"
  token = "7cf33172d567dd2504e988a78f64c3"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/afs:/afs:ro", "/cache"]
  [runners.cache]
```

In the `Dockerfile`, we have a `RUN` command that copies the repo file from `AFS` to the *currently-being-built-image*, so we can install the software with `yum install`:

```
FROM gitlab-registry.ch/cc7-base

MAINTAINER Somebody

RUN echo "set completion-ignore-case On" >> /etc/inputrc
RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install -y \
        gcc \
        git \
        mc \
        python-devel \
        python-pip \
        svn \
        unzip \
        vim

RUN cp /afs/<hugePathHere>/Linux/RPM/cc7/custom-repo.repo /etc/yum.repos.d && \
    yum install --enablerepo=custom-repo -y CustomApp

CMD /bin/bash
```

---

The `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is:

```
services:
  - docker:dind

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - rtf-builder
  before_script:
    - docker info
    - docker login -u $DOCKER_LOGIN_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_LOGIN_PASSWORD gitlab-registry.ch
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t $TO .
    - docker push $TO
  after_script:
    - docker logout gitlab-registry.ch
  variables:
    TO: gitlab-registry.ch/<myUser>/testdockergitlabbuild:$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
```

But this always fails, with `GitLab-CI` telling me that

> cp: cannot stat
>   '/afs/*hugePathHere*/Linux/RPM/cc7/custom-repo.repo':
>   No such file or directory

- In the *host* machine, `AFS` is accesible and I can manually copy the
  repo file.
- A container created with `docker run --rm --privileged -ti -v /afs:/afs cc7-base`
  has `AFS` accesible.

Am I missing something to make `AFS` accesible from the `Dockerfile`?

**NOTE:**

`$DOCKER_LOGIN_USERNAME` and `$DOCKER_LOGIN_PASSWORD` are [GitLab secure variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html#user-defined-variables-secure-variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to have `AFS` and `Docker` together, **but not with a `Docker-in-Docker` runner**.

The trick is to use instead a `shell` runner.
So when *registering* the runner, we should do it like:

```
sudo gitlab-ci-multi-runner register -n \
  --url <GITLAB_CI_SERVER_URL> \
  --registration-token <PROJECT_TOKEN> \
  --executor shell \
  --tag-list "shell-builder" \
  --description "Shell builder for Docker images"
```

Afterwards, we just need [to install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/) and make it available for the `gitlab-runner` user  (for example, adding the user to the `docker` group).

As [stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050899/how-to-mount-host-volumes-into-docker-containers-in-dockerfile-during-build/26053710#26053710), we can't access the files inside `AFS` from the `Dockerfile`.

Instead, we can use a *2-step build*:

1. Build with the `Dockerfile` everything that doesn't need to access `AFS`.
2. Execute a script that will run a container from that image, with `AFS` mounted and install all the `AFS` related stuff.

Then, we just have to commit the container and push it to the registry as the final image.

---

As an example, the files involved in this process could be something like this:

### .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build

variables:
  TO: <GitLab Registry URL>/<project>:$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - shell-builder
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $DOCKER_LOGIN_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_LOGIN_PASSWORD <GitLab Registry URL>
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t $TO .
  after_script:
    - sh ./postBuild.sh $TO $GITLAB_USER_EMAIL
    - docker push $TO
    - docker logout <GitLab Registry URL>
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM <Some base image>

MAINTAINER <Somebody>

<Do everything not related to AFS>

CMD /bin/bash
```

### postBuild.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly imageName="$1"
readonly maintainer="$2"

readonly imageNameAsLatest="$imageName-latest"
readonly containerName="afs_mounted"

docker create -ti --privileged -v /afs:/afs --name="$containerName" "$imageName"
docker start "$containerName"

docker exec "$containerName" /bin/bash -c "cp /afs/LONG_AFS_PATH/Linux/CentOS7/custom-repo.repo /etc/yum.repos.d"
docker exec "$containerName" /bin/bash -c "yum install --enablerepo=custom-repo -y CustomApplication"

docker commit -a "$maintainer" -m "Mounted AFS in a container and installed CustomApplication." "$containerName" "$imageName"

docker tag "$imageName" "$imageNameAsLatest"

docker stop "$containerName"
docker rm "$containerName"
```