# Can I build a Docker image that needs a volume mount to do its work?

Tags: docker

Is there a way to have a volume mounted during `docker build` so that RUN commands can see resources from the volume?

Comment: Maybe of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050899/how-to-mount-host-volumes-into-docker-containers-in-dockerfile-during-build?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mount host volumes into docker containers in Dockerfile during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050899/how-to-mount-host-volumes-into-docker-containers-in-dockerfile-during-build)