# Docker: How can I have sqlite db changes persist to the db file?

Tags: sqlite, docker, dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.8

ADD . /go/src/beginnerapp

RUN go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux

RUN go get github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3

RUN go install beginnerapp/

VOLUME /go/src/beginnerapp/local-db

WORKDIR /go/src/beginnerapp

ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/beginnerapp

EXPOSE 8080
```

The sqlite db file is in the `local-db` directory but I don't seem to be using the `VOLUME` command correctly. Any ideas how I can have db changes to the sqlite db file persisted?

I don't mind if the volume is mounted before or after the build.

I also tried running the following command

```
user@cardboardlaptop:~/go/src/beginnerapp$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -v ./local-db:/go/src/beginnerapp/local-db beginnerapp
```

docker: Error response from daemon: create ./local-db: "./local-db" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.

EDIT: Works with using `/absolutepath/local-db` instead of relative path `./local-db`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mount host volumes into docker containers in Dockerfile during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050899/how-to-mount-host-volumes-into-docker-containers-in-dockerfile-during-build)

Comment: It is not persisting after you run the container and make changes? That is because you didn't mount the volume

Comment: @tima I don't need it to mount during the build. Before or After is fine

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are not *mounting* volumes in a Dockerfile. 
VOLUME  tells docker that content on those directories can be mounted via docker run --volumes-from

You're right. Docker doesn't allow relative paths on volumes on command line.

Run your docker using absolute path:

`docker run -v /host/db/local-db:/go/src/beginnerapp/local-db`

Your db will be persisted in the host file `/host/db/local-db`

If you want to use relative paths, you can make it work with docker-compose with "volumes" tag:

```
volumes:
  - ./local-db:/go/src/beginnerapp/local-db
```

You can try this configuration:

- Put the Dockerfile in a directory, (e.g. `/opt/docker/myproject`)
- create a `docker-compose.yml` file in the same path like this:

> ```
> version: "2.0"
> services:
>   myproject:
>     build: .
>     volumes:
>       - "./local-db:/go/src/beginnerapp/local-db"
> ```

- Execute `docker-compose up -d myproject` in the same path.

Your db should be stored in `/opt/docker/myproject/local-db`

Just a comment. The content of local-db (if any) will be replaced by the content of `./local-db` path (empty). If the container have any information (initialized database) will be a good idea to copy it with `docker cp` or include any init logic on an entrypoint or command shell script.

Comment: Works with the absolute path, couldn't use `./local-db` though

Comment: With docker-compose ,the host path can be relative to docker-compose.yml file, and it is a good practice e.g volumes:
  - ./db/local-db:/go/src/beginnerapp/local-db

Comment: Should I use docker-compose even though I have only 1 container?

Comment: docker-compose is a good docker solution. You can use it even if you have a single docker container. I improve my response to try to help you

Comment: Could this be accomplished using bind mounts? I can't get the data to persist following the official bind mount tutorial https://docs.docker.com/get-started/06_bind_mounts/

Answer (score 0):

In Docker windows, you can use relative path from project directory like this (where 'app' is a project directory and 'mnt' is a sub-directory holding some file/s to be mount/ed):

```
docker run -v %cd%\mnt:/app/mnt
```