# Permanent Superuser Django Docker

Tags: django, docker, django-models, django-rest-framework, dockerfile

So, I have a dockerfile that I run Django via CapRover to run the backend of my website. Amongst the components, I have an admin panel that I log into using a superuser that I've created by ssh-ing into the docker container. The problem is that whenever I change my backend by uploading it as a .tar via CapRover, I have to create my superuser again.

My question is, is there any way to avoid this by creating some sort of persistance? Or is there any way of automating this via my dockerfile?

Thanks!

Comment: How is your database configured?

Comment: @IainShelvington it's sqlite3, I'm not sure what exact info you need?

Comment: Where is the sqlite file being saved? You might want to think about moving to a persistent DB

Comment: The DB is saved outside the dockerfile, in the parent directory where Django runs. I have thought about switching to MySQL, but in the long run. Do you reckon that's the problem?

Comment: How is the DB mounted/referenced by the django container?

Comment: Following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147839/docker-how-can-i-have-sqlite-db-changes-persist-to-the-db-file

Comment: Can you share the command you are using to mount the sqlite file? When you upload the .tar are you deleting/overriding the existing file? I would seriously consider using a proper database, PostgreSQL is preferable unless you have no other option than to use MySQL in my opinion