# Can I have an output of a script running in a Docker container as a local folder?

Tags: docker

I am creating a Dockerfile, where my remote repo is cloned, then built.

Can I map that output folder inside Docker container to a local folder so that to have the build result in it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mount host volumes into docker containers in Dockerfile during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050899/how-to-mount-host-volumes-into-docker-containers-in-dockerfile-during-build)

Answer (score 3):

For something like this, I would not use `docker build`. Instead, create a Docker image that contains the necessary tools to build your project and use it as a "compiler". In the end, you want to be able to do:

```
$ docker run -v $(pwd):/output compiler
```

Building the project using a command has a lot of advantages over doing it during `docker build`:

- You are able to use volumes to mount local directories into the Docker container
- You can easily re-run single steps of your build process without having to re-run the whole build
- You can build the project, and use the build output for another image (e.g. build Javascript project and put it in `nginx` image)

Answer (score 0):

Not "mapped" from the container as such. Building and maps/mounts don't really coexist (unless you use something like [rocker](https://github.com/grammarly/rocker) to build). You can get a copy of the data from the built image though.

Via `tar`.

```
docker run --rm IMAGE tar -cf - /clone | tar -xvf -
```

Or [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

```
CID=$(docker create IMAGE)
docker cp $CID:/clone ./
docker rm -f $CID
```

Or use a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/), the data will be found in `Mountpoint` from inspect.

```
docker run --rm -v myclone:/clone IMAGE sleep 1
docker volume inspect myclone
```