# Docker mount volume with copy data from temp container

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, docker-volume

Consider the scenario

```
From package-alpine:latest as package

FROM alpine:latest
COPY --from=package /opt/raw /queue/raw
RUN filter-task /queue/raw --> this will change raw itself
```

Need a Volume here on queue so that, when I am running I can get the finished raw directly on host.

Wondering if its possible and if yes what is the syntax

Tried with docker volume but that actually make the queue directory empty

```
docker run -v $HOME/queue:/queue process:latest
```

Comment: Where is `filter-task` software from?

Comment: I think you can get the answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050899/how-to-mount-host-volumes-into-docker-containers-in-dockerfile-during-build

Answer (score 0):

What you define in your Dockerfile is executed in `build-phase` (build), not in `container-deployment (run) phase`.

You're creating volumes in `run` phase, so, `/queue` could not still exist.

So, I think you need to execute filter-task from `Dockerfile RUN command` to `docker run` command.

Just try with this:
**Dockerfile**

FROM alpine:latest
COPY ./filter-task

Create image:

```
docker build -t process:latest .
```

Run container with filter task as entrypoint, not in Dockerfile:

```
docker run -v /opt/raw:/queue/raw process:latest filter-task /queue/raw
```

At this point, when container is created, volume is mounted and data stored inside container in /queue/raw will be accesible in /opt/raw in host.
Your volume was empty because if you mount a volume that alrealdy exists in container, it's not mounted.