# Composer install with dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, composer-php, dockerfile

I'm pretty new with docker, I try to automatically execute composer install within my Dockerfile but it seems that I can't cd into my application while installing, what's wrong? Or maybe there is another better way to do that?

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.1"
services:

    app:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: app
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - ./Projects/app:/application/app
          - ./Docker/nginx/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf
      ports:
          - "8080:8080"

    php-fpm-app:
      build: Docker/php-fpm-app
      container_name: php-fpm-app
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - ./Projects:/application
          - ./Docker/php-fpm-app/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

my Dockerfile

```
FROM phpdockerio/php72-fpm:latest
WORKDIR "/application"

# Fix debconf warnings upon build
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/.composer \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/.composer

USER www-data

RUN cd /application/app; composer install
```

The output after I run this command:

> docker-compose up -d

```
Step 6/6 : RUN cd /application/app; composer install
 ---> Running in ac53e653af46
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /application/app
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /application
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
ERROR: Service 'php-fpm-app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c cd /application/app; composer install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

If I try to remove the last line from my Dockerfile, once it's up and running if I run this command:

> docker-compose exec --user www-data php-fpm-app bash -c 'cd
>   /application/app && composer install'

It works, I don't understand why I can't do this with my Dockerfile.

===========================
**Finally**
I find a way to execute a script but I don't see the output, so if the script last for many secondes/minutes I won't know when it's done.

```
ADD ./setup.sh /setup.sh
RUN chmod +x /setup.sh
CMD ["sh", "/setup.sh"]
```

I decided to execute this script manually once all it's up and running

```
sh ./setup.sh
```

Comment: omit the "composer install" part for once, and log in to the container (once its up and running), and manually try to issue composer install inside the container.

Comment: Yes, it works if I do it once its up and running

Comment: the question is not about the existence of composer.json. it is there. but your error is that it cannot cd into /application/app, and since your WORKDIR is /application, it fall backs to this directory, and thus if you look into your error, it says that it cannot find composer.json in /application
`/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /application/app
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /application`

Comment: and instead of WORKDIR /application, may be try setting it to /application/app, and remove `RUN cd /application/app` and just do `RUN composer install`

Comment: I already tried this solution but it seems that it didn't find the files before it's up and running

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mount host volumes into docker containers in Dockerfile during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050899/how-to-mount-host-volumes-into-docker-containers-in-dockerfile-during-build)

Comment: The “volume” directives in the `docker-compose.yml` file have no effect on the image build; you need to COPY your application code in.  (At which point mounting the volume over it is kind of redundant, if you don’t mind a workflow where you need to test-build-run after making changes.)

Comment: Maybe there is a way of running some command or script once it's up?

Answer (score 6):

You should not run composer install in Dockerfile. It will fail because you have not created/synced volume from the local to container yet. Thus all files including composer.json is not placed under /var/www/html.

What you can do is to add 1 line (command) into your docker-compose.yaml file inside the service eg.

```
services:
  api-php-fpm:
    build: ./docker/php-fpm
    command: sh -c "composer install"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the volumes aren't mounted until the build is complete.  Just use COPY to copy *only* the composer.json into the folder, and run the composer install as normal.

Answer (score -3):

Referencing the [Documentation for Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) you need to edit your Dockerfile.

it should be:

```
WORKDIR /application/app
RUN composer install
```

Does this fix your problem?

Comment: Step 6/6 : RUN composer install
 ---> Running in 9821f69e3ce0
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /application/app

But there is a composer.json file