# composer install not working php-alpine docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I am using php FPM alpine container with nginx alpine container for my laravel application.

Here is my Dockerfile,

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install composer
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
RUN php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

# copy files
COPY ./ /usr/src/app/

# install packages
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1
RUN composer install
```

Here is my docker-compose file,

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:1.19-alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ../api:/usr/src/app
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    depends_on:
      - api

  api:
    build: ../api
    volumes:
      - ../api:/usr/src/app
```

When I run `docker-compose up --build` the container build process works as you can see in the attached screenshot but the `vendor` directory was never created by the composer!?

[image]

Is it a known issue while using PHP FPM Alpine containers?

Also, when I access into the container using this command

```
docker exec -it docker_api_1 /bin/ash
```

and run `composer install` manually then everything works. Any suggestions are appreciated.

This is the error message when i visit the site. It can't find the composer autoload.php file,
[image]

Comment: This happens because you are, at run time, removing everything that was done by composer by mounting your host folder back over */usr/src/app*

Comment: You have to run `composer install` in an entrypoint.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185927/composer-install-with-dockerfile

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thanks for the help! I just removed the volume mount from api service, but now it shows permission error: `file_put_contents(/usr/src/app/storage/framework/sessions/qyNi95ds9AT6cCM3l5sZyS): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: `it shows permission error` => did you check the permissions ? what are they ? What have you tried to debug/fix that ?