# Dockerfile : How to mount host directory in container path?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

If i have inside my localhost a log folder at:

```
/var
  /logs
     apache.logs
     elasticsearch.logs
     etc...
```

And i want to mount ***/var/logs*** directory of my host, into a path inside a Docker container, like ***/usr/var/logs/*** , how do i do that within a dockerfile ?  So each time a log file is updated, it would be accessible within the container too.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not mount a `volumn` in `Dockerfile`

**Because:**

`Dockerfile` will build an `image`, `image` is independent on each machine host.

`Image` should be run everywhere on the same platform `for example on linux platform it can be running on fedora, centos, ubuntu, redhat...etc`

So you just mount `volumn` in to the `container` only. because `container` will be run on specify machine host.

Hope you understand it. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Try [-v option](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag) of `docker run` command.

`docker run -itd -v /var/logs:/usr/var/logs image-name`

This will mount `/var/logs` directory of host on to `/usr/var/logs` directory of container.

Hope this helps.

**Update:**

To mount directory with `source` and `dest` in dockerfile make use of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050899/how-to-mount-host-volumes-into-docker-containers-in-dockerfile-during-build) hack (Not 100% sure though).

```
RUN --mount=target=/usr/var/logs,type=bind,source=/var/logs
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mchawre. But how we do that in a dockerfile ?

Comment: `VOLUME` option in dockerfile might help, but there you can't provide source directory on host. Just try this hack mentioned in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050899/how-to-mount-host-volumes-into-docker-containers-in-dockerfile-during-build

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: which hack are you talking about ? i've red all the post but there isn't a solution with dockerfile unfortunately. And in my case i have to do it with a dockerfile due to some constraints

Comment: Can you try the command I mentioned in my answer. I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Oh sorry @mchawre, i did not see. Yes i will try this one as soon as i have my laptop afront of me, definitely . I really hope it works that would be awesome !

Comment: sorry but it does not work. Finally i understood that a dockerfile is not meant to have actions on the host part

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in two ways - https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

#### --mount

```
$ docker run -d -it --name devtest --mount type=bind,source=/var/logs,target=/usr/var/logs image:tag
```

#### -v

```
$ docker run -d -it --name devtest -v /var/logs:/usr/var/logs image:tag
```

Comment: Hi @Prakash Krishna , how do we do that in a dockerfile ?

Comment: The use of —mount is discouraged. —volume should be used in all cases