# How to add host cache directory to docker image when building?

Tags: c#, docker, caching, nuget

I'm fresher for docker. 
I had a bad network. Every time building the asp.net core project,it always stuck at **dotnet restore** step.

Because the project reference abp myget nightly. The error information:

> Step 8/9 : RUN dotnet restore "IC.AuthServer.csproj"
>    ---> Running in 4232f5677921
>     Failed to download package 'Volo.Abp.Core.0.19.0-preview20190724' from 'https://www.myget.org/F/abp-nightly/api/v3/flatcontainer/volo.abp.core/0.19.0-preview20190724/volo.abp.core.0.19.0-preview20190724.nupkg'.
>     The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
>       Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.
>       Connection reset by peer
>     Failed to download package 'Volo.Abp.IdentityServer.Domain.Shared.0.19.0-preview20190724' from 'https://www.myget.org/F/abp-nightly/api/v3/flatcontainer/volo.abp.identityserver.domain.shared/0.19.0-preview20190724/volo.abp.identityserver.domain.shared.0.19.0-preview20190724.nupkg'.
>     The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
>       Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.

I had get abp packages at ~/.nuget/. I attempt copy this to docker. but copy not support absolute path. Through I can copy it to current context directory. but it's so ugly .

Is there any way to mount host directory  when building image?

Thanks in advance.

Here is Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db-mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - mysql_init_files:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "Coriander_Account"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "123456"

  auth-server:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Applications/IC.AuthServer.Host/Dockerfile
    depends_on: 
      - db-mysql
    ports: 
      - "6001:80"

volumes: 
  mysql_data:
  dbdata:
  mysql_init_files:
```

Here is  Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Applications/IC.AuthServer.Host/"

// * I want to let docker mounting host directory at here. * 

RUN dotnet restore "IC.AuthServer.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "IC.AuthServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "IC.AuthServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IC.AuthServer.dll"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to mount host directory when building image?

Mounting host volumes during build is not possible (see this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52762779/9321274)). However, you could use [multistage builds](https://vsupalov.com/cache-docker-build-dependencies-without-volume-mounting/) and "mount" your host directory during a first *disk space inefficient* stage, and copy just what you need in the final step:

```
FROM ubuntu as intermediate
COPY myFiles /myFiles
RUN ... # some expensive operation

FROM ubuntu
COPY --from=intermediate /result /result
# simply use the result
```

Comment: my project is /home/user/workspace/CloudStorage/docker-compose.yml and  the cache path is /home/user/.nuget  .  According your operation, i must copy the .nuget directory to /home/user/workspace/CloudStorage/.nuget?  Is it?

Comment: One solution is to `COPY /home/user/workspace/CloudStorage/.nuget /nuget`. Your `nuget` folder will be copied in the docker container in `/nuget`

Comment: I test with your way.  But copy absuolute path  is not work . It will special a temp path. Error : failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder494280566/home/echo/.nuget: no such file or directory

Comment: Probably because you are using path outside of context for ADD/COPY commands. You should use relative path from your build context. See also https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1922#issuecomment-491245969

Comment: Thanks Thibaud,  I run Dockerfile from Docker-Compose. I'll replenish my answer.