# Docker run --mount make all files available in a different folder during RUN

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-buildkit

I want to make a folder on my host machine available during a `RUN` statement. That is, similar to the effect of a container run with `-v`:

```
docker run -v /path/on/host:/path/in/container mycontainer:tag
```

In the container this gives me `/path/in/container` with all files/folder in `path/on/host`.

To this end I am trying the experimental mount options from https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md:

```
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/path/on/host
```

This gives me a folder `/path/on/host` during the `RUN`.

I then have two problems:

1. I can `ls` files inside `/path/on/host`, but not use them (e.g. `cat` them). I have tried changing `type` to e.g. `cache` and using `source` like in https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/6078/in-a-dockerfile-is-there-a-way-to-avoid-copying-files-to-make-them-accessible-t, but I cannot make it work.
2. I cannot figure out how to have a different path inside the "`RUN` image", that is, `/path/in/container` instead of `/path/on/host`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood what the `RUN --mount=type=bind...` syntax is for. From the documentation:

> This mount type allows binding directories (read-only) in the context or in an image to the build container.

In other words, this does not permit you to access arbitrary host directories in the build stage. It is *not* an analog to the `-v` command line option on `docker run`. It only permits you to:

- Mount directories from your build context, or
- Mount directories from another stage in a multi-stage build

So for example I can do this do mount a directory from one build stage into a subsequent build stage:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental

FROM centos AS centos

FROM alpine
RUN --mount=type=bind,from=centos,source=/,target=/centos ls /centos > /root/centos.txt
```

Or if I have a directory named `example` in my build context, I can do this to mount it during the build process:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental

FROM centos AS centos

FROM alpine
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=example,target=/data cp /data/* /root/
```

The syntax you're using (with no `from` specified)...

```
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/path/on/host
```

...simply mounts the root of your build context on `/path/on/host` inside the container. Remember that `target` specifies the mountpoint *inside the container*.  E.g., if my build context looks like this:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── example
    └── README.md
```

And `example/README.md` contains:

```
This is a test.
```

And the `Dockerfile` contains a `RUN` option similar to what you're using:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental

FROM centos AS centos

FROM alpine
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/data cat /data/example/README.md > /root/README.md
```

Then when the image is built, `/root/README.md` has the contents of `example/README.md`.

Comment: You are right -- I had misunderstood the docs. Thanks for clarifying!
I suppose there no way of doing the mount I am looking for?

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for clarifying the feature and documentation ! In my case I had issues with the `source`, I missed that source was relative to the context hence I got `failed to compute cache key: "/Users/bric3/opensource/panama-foreign" not found: not found`. By the way `# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental` is not anymore necessary in recent docker versions.

Comment: Doesn't `docker build -v ...`  work for you during the Dockerfile build?  Seems to me that it would work.

Comment: At least according to the man page and `docker build --help`, there is no `-v` option to `docker build`.

Comment: Thanks @larsks, I had understood "This mount type allows binding directories (read-only) in the context or in an image to the build container" (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypebind) to mean any image but it actually means other images within your multi-stage build  right?

Comment: I wanted to do the same but came up on this limitation to mount only within the host build context.  My solution is to run a script that does the build.  At the beginning of the script I bind mount (bindfs) what I need in  the context then I can then mount it in the build container per this answer, then unmount it afterwards.   Alternately you can rsync a folder into the context and delete it after the build.  Both ways work for me.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that docker supports multiple build-contexts from the host using the `--build-context flag`: https://www.docker.com/blog/dockerfiles-now-support-multiple-build-contexts/. So you should be able to specify any host dir you want to mount as a separate `--build-context` and then use that. For example `docker build --build-context mydir=/myhostdir` and then in the Dockerfile do `RUN --mount=type=bind,from=mydir,target/whatever`.

Comment: the --build-context flag deserves more attention than being folded currently. Is it read-only as well @JonasKello? The doc didn't make it clear on that.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar use-case where I wanted to make my Maven repository from my host available to the container (to include some SNAPSHOTs that I had built locally).

I added an additional build context to the docker command

```
--build-context mvnrepo=/home/user/.m2/
```

and the following to the Dockerfile

```
RUN --mount=from=mvnrepo,target=/root/.m2,readwrite
```

Comment: Does this actually work? The docs seem to indicate even if you specify `readwrite` that the data is discarded - https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/reference.md#run---mounttypebind