# Docker mount type bind while build is failing

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-build, docker-buildkit

I am using docker build kit to build by docker image.

I want bind the host volume to cache the libraries, I am using mount type bind. Here is my docker file. (ref from [here](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md#run---mounttypebind-the-default-mount-type) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/))

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM maven:3.6.2-jdk-8-slim AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./pom.xml .
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=/home/ubuntu/.m2,target=/root/.m2,rw mvn clean dependency:go-offline -B
COPY ./src ./src
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=/home/ubuntu/.m2,target=/root/.m2,rw mvn package


FROM tomcat:9.0.30-jdk8-openjdk
COPY --from=build /app/target/service.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

The syntax `RUN --mount=type=bind,source=/home/ubuntu/.m2,target=/root/.m2,rw mvn clean dependency:go-offline -B` is throwing following error.

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: 
failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = 
failed to build LLB: failed to compute cache key: "/home/ubuntu/.m2" not found: not found
```

I checked, the path `/home/ubuntu/.m2` exists. Is there any issue in syntax?

I was earlier using `--mount=type=cache`, it was working perfectly. The reason I want to switch to this is, if the downloaded maven libraries are stored in the host file system it self then even if we do `docker system prune --all`, we don't need to download the cached libraries again.

Comment: Check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599736/docker-run-mount-make-all-files-available-in-a-different-folder-during-run) .