# tmpfs mount for dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, filesystems, tmpfs

I want to mount a tmpfs filesystem in docker container.
For this I am passing mount command like this:

> docker run --mount
> type=tmpfs,destination=/tempdisk,tmpfs-mode=770,tmpfs-size=4m --name
> projectname projectname:latest

The above command is working perfectly fine.

Is there a way to do this in dockerfile? or through shell script?
I tried to implement through dockerfile like below:

```
RUN mkdir -p /tmpfolder
RUN chmod 777 /tmpfolder
RUN mount -t tmpfs -o size=32m tmpfs /tmpfolder
```

But it gives error at 3rd line when I do docker build as:

```
 mount: permission denied
```

Please guide me regarding this.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050899/how-to-mount-host-volumes-into-docker-containers-in-dockerfile-during-build help?

Comment: I had to manually run these sudo commands to make it work

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to do this from a Dockerfile.

Possible alternatives depend on what your final goal is:

- If you need to create some temporary files during one step, and exclude them from the resulting image, then delete them within the same step.
- If you need to create some temporary files and access them across several steps, but exclude them from the final image, then use [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/).
- If you just want to use a tmpfs to speed up the build, try [enabling Buildkit](https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/#getting-started).
- If you want to configure a path inside the image where the user can specify a specific filesystem (including a tmpfs), use [the `VOLUME` dockerfile instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume).
- If you really need very specifically a tmpfs while the image is running, it might be possible to do this from a running container (i.e. a script launched with `docker run ...`) if [the container is privileged](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities).