# Docker / Oracle Database / Volume Persistence / Create Table space

Tags: database, oracle, docker, volume, tablespace

I am building a Dev Docker environment and I have to set up an Oracle 19c database.

I have been successful... but not at 100%.

Everything is running correctly, I can create a tablespace, a user/schema, create a table, insert data, access via NodeJs the data too until I restart the container.

In all the tutorials, it is shown to mount a volume pointing to `/opt/oracle/oradata`

```
volumes:
    - ./database/OracleDB/oradata:/opt/oracle/oradata
```

But the tablespace are created by default in the `/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs`

I tried to add a volume pointing to that directory

```
volumes:
    - ./database/OracleDB/oradata:/opt/oracle/oradata
    - ./database/OracleDB/dbs:/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/
```

But I receive the following error `Error response from daemon: path /home/myusr/docker-base/database/OracleDB/dbs is mounted on / but it is not a shared mount.`

Anybody has already faced this issue and found a solution?

I continue of course to search to a solution ;)

*System Information*

Windows 10 Professionnal with WSL2

Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d

Oracle Database 19c

UPDATE 1
Based on Roberto Comments. Unfortunately, it is not working.
[image: console]

UPDATE 2
I tried the following

```
CREATE TABLESPACE tbs1_test DATAFILE '/opt/oracle/oradata/tbs1_test' SIZE 100 M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 100 M MAXSIZE 10 G;
```

and it as created the file in the desired location

Comment: I think it is telling you that this `/home/myusr/docker-base/database/OracleDB/dbs` is already mounted on `/` , therefore you can't mount it on a different volume. How did you create the tablespace ?? If you did not specify path, Oracle uses the default destination of `db_file_create_dest` . Connect to the docker and to the database and run the query `select file_name from dba_data_files order by 1;`

Comment: Straight forward: `CREATE TABLESPACE tbs1_test DATAFILE 'tbs1_test' SIZE 100 M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 100 M MAXSIZE 10 G;` I know That I can add the full path to the command and add `/opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/ORCLPDB` but I am searching for a less fixed solution

Comment: I will put an answer with steps, then we can move forward from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't change the value of `db_create_file_dest`, Oracle will use it as default destination for datafiles. In your case, when you executed your `create tablespace` command, the datafile was created in the default location. That is why it does not appear on your desired directory.

1.Connect as sysdba to the database

2.Execute

```
SQL> alter system set db_create_file_dest = '/opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB' scope=both;
```

3.As you have a volume already in the above directory, remove the other volume specification, as it is already shared under `/`

4.Remove the tablespace and create it back again ( if it is empty )

```
SQL> DROP TABLESPACE tbs1_test including contents and datafiles;
SQL> CREATE TABLESPACE tbs1_test DATAFILE 'tbs1_test' SIZE 100 M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 100 M MAXSIZE 10 G;
```

5.Verify that the datafile now is in the right volume

```
SQL> select file_id, file_name from dba_data_files where tablespace_name = 'TBS1_TEST' ;
```

If you want to dig more in how to create specific volumes inside a docker image, check this post in Stackoverflow, it is one of the best IMHO

[How to mount host volumes into docker containers in Dockerfile during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050899/how-to-mount-host-volumes-into-docker-containers-in-dockerfile-during-build?rq=1)

Comment: You made a typo error "db_file_create_dest" should be "db_create_file_dest".
And it has not worked... The file is still created in the dbhome_1/dbs directory

Comment: sorry, you are right. it is `db_create_file_dest`. my mystake. Can you show me the value of the  parameter ?  and also a select over the dba_data_files ? you can edit the question and put the information there

Comment: the value is wrong, it should contain the whole path until the datafilename. I edited the answer.