# How can I use a volume in context of build directive of docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I define a volume in `docker-compose` as follows

```
volumes:
  root_volume:
    driver: local,
    driver_opts:
        device:"/home/user/test",
        type:none
```

I need to do something like this

```
  nginx:
    build:
      context: root_volume
      dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile
    container_name: test_nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8015:80"
    networks:
      - test_network
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What are you hoping that volume declaration will do?  Volumes aren't considered or used at all as part of the image build, and they also aren't used when running a container if you don't include a separate `volumes:` block as part of the service definition.  It's possible a best-practice approach would be to delete this volume definition entirely.

Comment: [How to mount host volumes into docker containers in Dockerfile during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050899/how-to-mount-host-volumes-into-docker-containers-in-dockerfile-during-build) may answer your larger question (TL;DR: you can't, except in the context of mounting read-only content into individual `RUN` instructions).

Comment: @DavidMaze As you know I have merged many `docker-compose` files. The relative path in `build` loads the first path defined in `.env`. I was going to define the absolute path in `volume` and use that volume in different directives of `docker-compose` file, including `build` directive.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that volumes defined at the top level can't be directly used as build contexts. Instead, define the volume as normal at the top level.
Then in the service, mount that volume at a specific path in the container using the `volumes` option.
The build context should be `.` (the current directory) and reference the Dockerfile as normal.

Example:

```
volumes:
  root_volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/user/test
      o: bind

services:

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - root_volume:/path/in/container
    container_name: test_nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
     - "8015:80"
    networks:
     - test_network
```

This will mount the host directory into the container, making it available at the specified path during the build.

Comment: Volumes are _never_ available during the build.  The actual effect of this will cause the contents of the named volume (itself defined as a host directory here) to hide the image's contents, resulting in a container that might not have the filesystem contents you expect.