# Chmod in Dockerfile: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile, volume, chmod

I try to build a Jupyterhub Docker Image and cannot use `chmod` on the volumes.
My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM jupyterhub/jupyterhub:latest

RUN pip install --no-cache \
    oauthenticator \
    dockerspawner \
    jupyterhub-nativeauthenticator


COPY jupyterhub_config.py /srv/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py

WORKDIR /srv/jupyterhub
VOLUME /srv/jupyterhub/shared_data

RUN chmod 777 /srv/jupyterhub/shared_data
```

building this leads to the following error:
`> [6/6] RUN chmod 777 /srv/jupyterhub/shared_data: 0.118 chmod: cannot access '/srv/jupyterhub/shared_data': No such file or directory`

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Volumes are not present at image build time, but at container runtime.

Comment: [How to mount host volumes into docker containers in Dockerfile during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050899/how-to-mount-host-volumes-into-docker-containers-in-dockerfile-during-build) and its answers show how to mount directories from the context at image build time, but those mounts are read-only.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I basically just want to create **persistent** a folder in the container where I can read and write to, and that I can share with other containers. Basically a shared folder between containers. What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: A volume is the easiest way. Just remove the `RUN chmod 777 /srv/jupyterhub/shared_data`.

Comment: @Turing85 hm? Actually `mkdir ... && chmod...` is the common way to resolve permissions issue for volumes mounted to non-root containers - folder contents, if any, will be replaced by volume, but permissions will be retained. If you have a non-root user, it's (as far as I know) the only way to be able to write to directory where volume is mounted. Dockerfile in question is rather missing mkdir than has unnecessary instruction.

Comment: @STerliakov wouldn't this entail that the user starting the container has either root-access or is the owner of the directory? Otherwise they cannot `chmod` on said directory.

Comment: @Turing85 do you mean host directory? Maybe yes, I never checked that (all my docker use cases are interacting with docker only with sudo). But you can always use a named volume if mounting a "real" directory causes any troubles.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see what you mean now. Yep, but it's not a big problem, you can always activate another user in Dockerfile to apply permissions and change back.

Comment: @STerliakov how do you want to switch the user? And to which user do you want to switch?

Comment: @Turing85 with `USER` instruction?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255848/discussion-between-turing85-and-sterliakov).

Answer (score 1):

You should entirely delete that `RUN` line.  Also consider deleting the `VOLUME` line before it.

From a security point of view, changing a directory (or anything) to mode 0777 is almost never considered a best practice.  It allows any user to overwrite any other user's content; "overwrite" could include subtle changes to content or injecting malware into binaries.

In the case of a Docker container, there will be only a single process inside the container, so there's no reason to use an actively insecure setup.  Leave the default file mode of 0755 (writable only by the owner) and make sure the container user is correct.  Since this directory will eventually be a volume mount, you can figure out what (numeric) user ID owns the host directory

```bash
ls -lnd ./shared_data
```

and then launch the container as that specific numeric user ID.

```bash
docker run -u 1001 -v "$PWD/shared_data:/srv/jupyterhub/shared_data" ...
```

With this volume mount, the container directory is completely replaced by the host directory, including its ownership and permission.  That means that, ignoring the error, the `RUN chmod` command still won't have an effect because a different directory will replace it.  You can't make changes to the eventual mounted directory from the Dockerfile.

The volume mount also doesn't require a Dockerfile `VOLUME` directive.  It's not impossible that the `VOLUME` is causing the specific error you're seeing here.  The most obvious effect of `VOLUME` is to prevent any further changes to the named directory in the image, so again the `RUN chmod` won't have an effect; its second most obvious effect will be to leak anonymous volumes.  Unless you're clear on what `VOLUME` does and why you want it, it's almost always safe to just delete that line.